# Bidirectional dependency with Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm experimenting with VIPER architecture in my Android app. I use Dagger 2.11 for DI.

Dependencies I have for each VIPER module are:

1. `Presenter` and `Fragment` are linked via `ViewInput` and `ViewOutput` interfaces.
2. `Presenter` and `Interactor` are linked via `InteractorInput` and `InteractorOutput` interfaces.
3. Some other dependencies, we are not interested in.

This is how my Dagger Module looks like:

```
Module(includes = [Module.Declarations::class])
class Module(private val viewInput: ViewInput) {

    @Module
    interface Declarations {

        @Binds
        @FragmentLevel
        fun bindViewOutput(viewOutput: Presenter): ViewOutput

        @Binds
        @FragmentLevel
        fun bindInteractorOutput(interactorOutput: Presenter): InteractorOutput

        @Binds
        @FragmentLevel
        fun bindInteractorInput(interactorInput: Interactor): InteractorInput
    }

    @Provides
    @FragmentLevel
    fun provideViewInput() = viewInput
}
```

Now when I call `inject` in my `Fragment` the following happens:

1. `Presenter` is injected into `Fragment` via `ViewOutput` interface
2. `Interactor` is injected into `Presenter` via `InteractorInput` interface
3. `Presenter` is **not** injected into `Interactor`, because of `Lazy` type (to prevent cyclic dependencies).
4. After the first call of `Lazy.get()` `Presenter` is injected into `Interactor` via `InteractorOutput` interface.

The problem is that in the 1st and 4th steps **different** instances of `Presenter` are injected. How can I make dagger inject the same presenter into `Fragment` and `Interactor`?

Or maybe I need to fix the dependency cycle in the other way?

Comment: Have you tried using Singleton DI . From your question its the only thing that i can think of now.  Try
@Singleton 
Try this reference to know more.. 
https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-part-i-basic-principles-graph-dependencies-scopes-3dfd032ccd82

Comment: @SijanGurung I already have FrgamentLevel scope for each module dependencies. Singleton scope is top-level and can't by applied in my situation. By the way, I've already found the answer (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed after adding `@FragmentLevel` scope to `Presenter`.